# Downloading external sources is disabled on Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I’m currently facing an issue with my Eclipse IDE where downloading external sources is disabled on my config.xml file(It is a Maven project) after restarting/reopening the IDE. Here are the solutions I’ve tried so far:

- Navigated to Window -> Preferences -> Maven and checked ‘Download
  Artifact Sources’ and ‘Download Artifact JavaDoc’.
- Performed XML validation.
- Updated the Maven Project.
- Cleared the cache and cleaned the project.

Despite these attempts, the issue persists. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could suggest any other solutions or point out if I’m doing something wrong. Thank you in advance for your help!

Despite these attempts, the issue persists. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could suggest any other solutions or point out if I’m doing something wrong. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the following way can solve this problem.

- Open the Eclipse preferences window (Window > Preferences),Go to XML(Wild Web Developer).
- check the "Download external resources like referenced DTD,XSD", then Apply.